# Why is the velocity and accleration vector not necessarily perpendicular

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have read somewhere that the velocity vector and the acceleration vector are not necessarily perpendicular.

I don't really understand why, since velocity and acceleration are represented by:

$$ v = \frac{dr(t)}{dt} $$
$$ a = \frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2} $$

and if $r(t)$ represents a position vector on a curve, then $\frac{dr(t)}{dt} $ and $\frac{d^2r(t)}{dt^2}$, represents its tangent and normal vector respectively, which by definition are perpendicular.

So what is the error here?

Comment: Why do you think that $\dfrac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ is normal to the curve?

Comment: The second derivative isn't generally normal to the curve. Only when the parametrisation is with constant speed.

Comment: @user_of_math I understood it from http://mathwiki.ucdavis.edu/Calculus/Vector_Calculus/Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/Curvature_and_Normal_Vectors_of_a_Curve. 

Where $T = \frac{dr}{dt}$ and $N = \frac{dT}{dt}$

Comment: Ah, but if you look carefully, $N$ is not $\mathrm dT/\mathrm dt$, it's $\mathrm d\hat T/\mathrm dt$ where $\hat T=T/\|T\|$. So $N\ne\mathrm dT/\mathrm dt=\mathrm d^2r/\mathrm dt^2$. // Also, for your larger question, consider a stone falling straight downwards.

Answer (score 1):

You're driving down the street and get T-Boned. Acceleration in the driver-side direction, but I bet you don't keep moving straight forward. Physics. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

Since the derivative of $\|r'\|^2$ is $2r'\cdot r''$, we have

$$r'\cdot r''=0\implies \|r'\|^2=\text{constant}$$

That is: the velocity and the acceleration are perpendicular if and only if the speed (the modulus of the velocity) is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Newton will help? His second law reads. $$ F= ma = m \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} r,$$ where $m$ is the mass of an object and $F$ is the force applied to it.

Think about a ball being thrown. Due to gravity its path will resemble a parabola (modulo pathological cases eg a tornado). Thus the second derivative of $r$ is the direction of "bending" of the path. I think this is a useful way to think about it.

In a world where $a$ would always be perpendicular to $r$ the ball would behave in a pretty weird way.

Comment: Of course if $a$ and $r$ point to the same direction, the object will gain speed and not change direction.